# Function call without an object or Class name

Tags: java

I am learning Java Swing. I have seen there are many functions which are called without using any class and object. How is this possible?

Some examples of these type of functions are:

```
setBackground()

setLayout().
```

Comment: This is not possible. Show us the code.

Comment: `this` or class name can be added implicitly.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to call methods without using a qualifier. Current class is implicit context. It works both for static and instance method. Same applies to variables.

Comment: Which type of function we call without using any qualifier? Is this possible to call every funtion without. using any qualifier? What is speacial thing in these functions so that we can call without using qualifier.

Comment: Any function (method) could be called with out of qualifier in Java.